# Accessing members of ListView delegate which is loaded by Loader

Tags: qt, listview, qml, loader

```
ListView {
    id: listView
    model: someModel {}
    delegate: Loader {
        id: delegateLoader
        source: {
            var where;
            if(model.type === 1) {
                where = "RadioQuestion.qml";
            }
            else
                where = "TextQuestion.qml";
            if(delegateLoader.status == Loader.Ready) {
                delegateLoader.item.question= model.question;
            }

            return Qt.resolvedUrl(where);
        }
}
```

I show some questions to user by using `ListView`. But I cannot access members of delegate loaded by Loader.

`RadioQuestion.qml` has Radio Buttons and Text is just text field. I just want to get all answers after pressing a submit button but I could not figure out how I can traverse among delegates.

Maybe my approach is wrong about building this structure. Therefore I am open for better solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Button {
    text: "Submit answers"
    onClicked: {
          for(var child in listView.contentItem.children) {
              var c = listView.contentItem.children[child].item;
              if(typeof c !== "undefined")
                   console.log(c.answer)
          }
    }
 }
```

You can get properties of loader delegate like this. We use "`undefined`" check, because one object in children of `contentItem` is undefined. That was second object in the list, I do not know why.

Answer (score 1):

Your `question` is already exposed through the model, so your delegates should directly bind to it, so assuming that `question` is a property of the model:

```
// from inside the delegate
question: delegateRootId.ListView.view.model.question
```

or assuming that question is a list element role:

```
// from inside the delegate
question: model.question
```

And if you were careful enough not to name the property inside the delegate `question` thus shadowing the model role, you could simply:

```
// from inside the delegate
questionSource: question
```

Not to mention that if your model "scheme" is known and it is a given that you will have a `question` role and that role will be displayed in the delegate, you don't even need any additional property in the delegate to begin with, you can bind the actual item directly to the question, for example:

```
// from inside the delegate
Text { text: question }
```

And that's all that's really needed.

Alternatively you can use a `Binding` or a `Connections` element or a simple signal handler to delay the operation until the loader has actually completed the loading. For example:

```
delegate: Loader {
        source: Qt.resolvedUrl(model.type === 1 ? "RadioQuestion.qml" : "TextQuestion.qml")
        onStatusChanged: if (status === Loader.Ready) if (item) item.question= model.question
}
```